# keras prediction expected shape=(None, 5, 9461), found shape=(None, 5, 8635)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am trying to load a keras model but i get the  ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5, 9461), found shape=(None, 5, 8635)
I tried finding a solution with existing posts but failed. I am a total beginner with machine learning so please understand my incompetence Thanks in advance.

```
text = "Seton Pasha moved one of the lights so as to illuminate a small oil
painting which hung above the sideboard" 
text = text.lower()



WORD_LENGTH = 5

#text = open('dope.txt').read().lower()
print('corpus length:', len(text))

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
words = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

unique_words = np.unique(words)
unique_word_index = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(unique_words))






model = load_model('model_dope.h5')
history = pickle.load(open("history_dope.p", "rb"))  


def prepare_input(text):
    x = np.zeros((1, WORD_LENGTH, len(unique_words)))
    for t, word in enumerate(text.split()):
        print(word)
        x[0, t, unique_word_index[word]] = 1
    return x
prepare_input("voices became audible and irvin".lower())


def sample(preds, top_n=3):
    preds = np.asarray(preds).astype('float64')
    preds = np.log(preds)
    exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
    preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
    return heapq.nlargest(top_n, range(len(preds)), preds.take)



def predict_completions(text, n=3):
    if text == "":
        return("0")
    x = prepare_input(text)
    print('---->    ',x)
    

    preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
    next_indices = sample(preds, n)
    return [unique_words[idx] for idx in next_indices]

print('')

q =  "voices became audible and irvin following a moment of hesitation crossed and opened the door"    #input here
print("correct sentence: ",q)
seq = " ".join(tokenizer.tokenize(q.lower())[0:5])    # q.lower())[0:5]
print("Sequence: ",seq)


print("next possible words: ", predict_completions(seq, 8))
```